# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 error

Tags: php, exif

i keep getting the following error and i don't no how to fix it! Help!

**Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\public_html\admin\includes\funcs.inc.php on line 51**

i do get the warning output error thought...

```
function getFileExtension($key) {
    $extensions = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF => '.gif', IMAGETYPE_JPEG => '.jpg', IMAGETYPE_PNG => '.png');

    $exifType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['artwork']['tmp_name'][$key]);   
    LINE 51 ---> $ext = $extensions[$exifType];

    return $ext;
}



$ext = getFileExtension($key);

if (!isset($ext)) {
    $warning = 'Error: Unsupported file type (supported images: gif, jpeg, png).';
}
```

Comment: And `$key` is..? Where's line 51? Did you upload the right files? What HTML did you use to do that? Can you prove it with `print_r`? What other debugging have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) indicates that it returns `false` when a valid signature is not detected.  If you try `$extensions[false]` you'll get your offset error, so this is probably what is occurring.

Comment: im uploading a pdf to see how the functions reacts... that is probably why it returns an offset error, coz it's not in the array extensions...

Comment: @Marco - exif-imagetype does not detect PDF.  You'll see there is no corresponding constant in the quoted documentation.

Comment: ok, i think i got it!  i've added a condition to check for the return value if ($exifType) return $extensions[$exifType];  that's seems to work

Comment: @Marco: And what do you return otherwise?

Comment: @Marco - That test only fixes a scenario where the return would be false such as you are testing against something that does not have exif headers.  You will still receive the error in a scenario where the file has a proper exif header but is not supported by your script.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if $_FILES['artwork']['tmp_name'] isn't empty ?
I suppose that your file wasn't uploaded.

You should provide more details or some debug informations

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you haven't declared the array keys with commas:

```
array(IMAGETYPE_GIF => '.gif', IMAGETYPE_JPEG => '.jpg', IMAGETYPE_PNG => '.png');
```

try to use this :

```
array('IMAGETYPE_GIF' => '.gif', 'IMAGETYPE_JPEG' => '.jpg', 'IMAGETYPE_PNG' => '.png');
```

And please let me know if it works.

Comment: IMAGETYPE_GIF etc... are exif_imagetype constants so quoting them in the array is incorrect.

Comment: try it, but it's not the commas

Comment: exif image types can be defined without . Eg : array (IMAGETYPE_GIF         => 'gif',     "mime_type" => 'image/gif'),

Answer (score 1):

You will receive an offset error in any case that exif_imagetype() returns a value that you do  not have defined in your array.  A better solution to prevent this is to test for the existence of the array key before you set your return value.

```
function getFileExtension($key) {
    $extensions = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF => '.gif', IMAGETYPE_JPEG => '.jpg', IMAGETYPE_PNG => '.png');

    $exifType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['artwork']['tmp_name'][$key]);

    // Add this test.
    // Modified because a value of false in $exifType will cause
    // array_key_exists() to fail.
    if($exifType && array_key_exists($exifType, $extensions)) {
        $ext = $extensions[$exifType];
    } else {
        $ext = false;
    }

    return $ext;
}

$ext = getFileExtension($key);

if (!isset($ext)) {
    $warning = 'Error: Unsupported file type (supported images: gif, jpeg, png).';
}
```

Updated to test for a value in $exifType so it doesn't cause array_key_exists() to fail.

Comment: Warning: array_key_exists() [function.array-key-exists]: The first argument should be either a string or an integer ....

Comment: it's probably because exif-imagetype does not detect PDF, therefore doesn't exist in the first place

Comment: the one that does work---> if ($exifType) return $extensions[$exifType];

Comment: I updated the answer with code that will work and won't give you the error from array_key_exists()